# Number of divisors equals square root

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

A colleague of mine mentioned that there was something special about the number nine.  He noticed that nine had three positive integer divisors {1, 3, 9} and the square root of nine is three.

His question was:  Are there any other positive integers n, such that the number of positive integer divisors of n is equal to the square root of n?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Yes, $1$ has positive integer divisor $\{1\}$, and $|\{1\}|=1=\sqrt{1}$.

Comment: Yes, one works!  Any more numbers with the given property?

Comment: Almost sure 1 and 3 are the only solutions. Type Length[Divisors[n^2]]-n, n=1...1000 into Wolfram Alpha, only 1st and 3rd equal zero and after 30 seems no possibility to achieve it again.   https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Length%5Bdivisors%5Bn%5E2%5D%5D-n%2C+n%3D1...1000

Answer (score 30):

The number of positive divisors is a [multiplicative function in the number theoretical sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function). The square root is also multiplicative. We can therefore proceed prime factor by prime factor. If `p` occurs in `n` `2k` times (an even number because `n` is a perfect square) then this contributes a factor of `p^k` to the square root and a factor of `2k+1` to the divisor count function. This rules out `p=2`. But for anything other than `p=3,k=1` `p^k` will be greater than `2k+1`. This leaves `1` and `9` as the only possible solutions.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @RobPratt I debated whether I should have accepted your answer or Loopy’s.  Loopy’s answer is more thorough than yours but I eventually decided to accept yours because 1) your answer was posted first AND 2) your answer technically answers my question the way I wrote it AND 3) I found your answer concise and easier to understand.

Comment: OK, thanks @WillOctagonGibson!